# Get iPhone info in C# application

Tags: c#, iphone, imei

I am looking for a way to retrieve information from an USB connected iPhone (IMEI, MODEL and so on).
Actually I would like to retrieve all the info possible as I am looking for an easy way to keep track of all the employees phones.

Comment: Is there an iPhone SDK or anything? Also, the driver needs to support this...

Answer (score 1):

with https://mobiledevice.codeplex.com you can read some basic informations like IMEI, MODEL and so on. All you need is the CoreFoundation.dll and iTunesMobileDevice.dll out of the iTunesSetup package

Comment: sorry for bumping such an old question, but what would i need the CoreFoundation.dll and iTunesMobileDevice.dll for ? i mean, where should it be placed ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm Sorry only devices in the Made for iTunes (MacBook,...) can communicate to the iPhone via the 30-pin dock connector. These devices also need to publish a protocol for applications to access them via the External Accessory framework.